# TTFB much longer in browser than tested by curl

Tags: angular, http, curl

I am trying to optimise performance of Angular application. I found that the most blocking operation is waiting for API response TTFB.

Result from Chrome network tab:

[image: TTFB Chrome]

test of the same endpoint by curl:

```sh
curl -o /dev/null -w "Connect: %{time_connect} TTFB: %{time_starttransfer} Total time: %{time_total} \n" http://api-endpoint.com/api/xyz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   897    0   897    0     0   2385      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2385
Connect: 0.005503 TTFB: 0.376242 Total time: 0.376443
```

I am really confused. Should I look for further optimisation in Angular application or blame backend?

Angular 9
Backend is written in Symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right, ask backend devs to investigate the issue.

in angular you can check that you don't spam backend with requests. If amount of requests the app sends is reasonable, then nothing to do here, only backend.

If you see duplicates, or redundant requests - try to avoid them.

Comment: How could the backend be a problem if the curl waiting time is OK?

Comment: For example, backend can handle 5-10 requests simultaneously. So if frontend is sending 15-20, then the last requests will hang and get higher TTFB and the first ones.